# Extract duplicated subset from a matrix by a vector

Tags: r, subset

The code:

```
a <- matrix(1:10, nrow=5)
b <- c(1, 4, 1)
a[a[, 1]%in%b, ]
```

The answer is:

```
     [, 1] [, 2]
[1, ] 1      6
[2, ] 4      9
```

Expected output:

```
     [, 1] [, 2]
[1, ] 1      6
[2, ] 4      9
[3, ] 1      6
```

That means that, the last 1 in vector b should get the corresponding value as well.
but use `%in%`, it seems like that the duplicated 1 was removed, I would like to keep
this value, and get 3 rows in the generated matrix.

Comment: assuming you're looking to match the values, as opposed to selecting rows, it's hard to do this with matrices, and a lot easier with data.frame's and even easier with data.table's - search for "merge" on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntactic sugar (together with super-speed) for this is achieved by `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

a = as.data.table(a)
setkey(a, V1)

a[J(b)]
#   V1 V2
#1:  1  6
#2:  4  9
#3:  1  6
```

If `b` is also a `data.table`, it's even nicer:

```
b = as.data.table(b)

a[b]
#   V1 V2
#1:  1  6
#2:  4  9
#3:  1  6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating things, try: `a[b, ]`

**EDIT:** Above only works by accident, as pointed out by @eddi.

Here is another way using `sapply`:

```
t(sapply(b,function(x){
  a[a[,1]==x,]
}))
```

Comment: this only works accidentally (I'm assuming the OP is looking for a merge and not to select specific rows); now had those been `data.table`'s, it would work on purpose

Comment: True, too late in the evening, better stick to TV :)